# User created browser function to debug R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `browser_if` function that activates a `browser()` statement when a condition is met (see below).  Is there a way to have `browser_if` behave like `browser` and stop execution in in the parent, rather than in the body of `browser_if`?

```
browser_if <- function(condition){
  if(condition) browser()
}
```

Comment: Check out the `?browser` help page, specifically, the `skipCalls=` parameter would seem to do what you want.

Comment: @MrFlick I've tried skipCalls=1, 2 and it doesn't break at the location of `browser_if`, but inside the function.  I'm using shiny modules, not sure if that has any effect.  Using `if(condition) browser()` explicitly in the code to break, which is messy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using only the `if` statement (without wrapping it in a function) or `browser`'s `expr` parameter.

from `?browser()`:

> The purpose of the expr argument is to allow for the illusion of
> conditional debugging. It is an illusion, because execution is always
> paused at the call to browser, but control is only passed to the
> evaluator described below if expr is not FALSE after coercion to
> logical. In most cases it is going to be more efficient to use an if
> statement in the calling program, but in some cases using this
> argument will be simpler.

Please run the following and set the slider to 10:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        browser(expr = {input$bins == 10})
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

Edit: passing a reactive to browser's `expr` argument:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  browser_condition <- reactive({
    input$bins == 10
  })
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    browser(expr = browser_condition())
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion.  The purpose of the break out into a separate function is so I can add further logic onto the condition if required.  I might turn it into `browser(expr = browser_expr(condition))` as a workaround.

Comment: @Vlad you can add as much logic to the `expr` argument as needed. Personally I don't see the point in splitting the browser call and its condition as in my workflow `browser` calls are always removed from the final code. However, passing (the result of) a function call to `expr` surely is a reasonable approach. Another would be to simply pass a variable (or when dealing with `shiny` a `reactive`/`reactiveVal`) populated somewhere else in your script. I left another example above.